# I am building a Double Linked List in Java, when I try to retrieve any information, it seems the next and previous node is always null

Tags: java, search, doubly-linked-list

I have been debugging this for hours and I cannot see any reason why my search method cannot find anything. and my toString only ever returns the first node, then again, nothing. can someone help me?

While debugging, I can confirm that the order of the list is correct, I can switch around the addLast and addFirst and will always return what should be the first element, but otherwise, I do not know. the first is always sored in head.info and during debugging I see that but then the prev and next are still null.
thanks in advance!

```
public class DoubleLinkedList {

  private DoubleNode head;

  public DoubleLinkedList() {
    head = null;
  }

  public class DoubleNode {
    int info;
    DoubleNode prev;
    DoubleNode next;

    public DoubleNode(int key) {
      info = key;
      prev = next = null;
    }
  }


  public DoubleNode search(int key) {
    DoubleNode current = this.head;

    while (current != null && current.info != key) {
      current = current.next;
    }
    return current;
  }

  public void addFirst(int key) {
    this.head = new DoubleNode(key);
  }

  public void addLast(int key) {
    DoubleNode node = new DoubleNode(key);
    DoubleNode current;

    if (head == null) {
      this.head = node;
    } else {
      current = this.head;
      while (current.next != null) {
        current = current.next;
        current.next = node;
        node.prev = current;
      }
    }
  }

  public int delete(int key) {
    DoubleNode current, sent;
    current = search( key );
    if (current != null) {
      sent = delete( current );
      return sent.info;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  }

  private DoubleNode delete(DoubleNode node) {
    if (node.prev != null) {
      (node.prev).next = node.next;
    } else {
      this.head = node.next;
    }
    if (node.next != null) {
      (node.next).prev = node.prev;
    }
    return node;
  }

  public String toString() {
    String string = "";
    while (head != null) {
      string += head.info + " ";
      head = head.next;
    }
    return string;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DoubleLinkedList test = new DoubleLinkedList();
    test.addLast( 3 );
    test.addLast( 5 );
    test.addFirst( 7 );
    System.out.println(test);
    System.out.println( "Search: " + test.search( 1 ) );
  }
}
```

The results come out as:

```
7,
Search: null
```

Answer (score 0):

Your addFirst method isn't currently setting the new head's `next` property.  It needs to be something more like this:

```
public void addFirst(int key) {
    DoubleNode node = new DoubleNode(key);
    node.next = this.head;
    this.head = node; 
}
```

Comment: This did help with my toString, it now prints all but the last digit, but my search is still coming up with null. Thank you though! you have already helped greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List list = new List();
    list.addNode("1");
    list.addNode("2");
    list.addNode("3");
    System.out.println(list);// not implemented
}
}

class List {
Node head;
Node tail;

class Node {
    Node next;
    Node previous;
    String info;

    public Node(String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }
}

void addNode(String info) {
    Node node = new Node(info);
    if (head == null) {
        head = tail = node;
    } else if(tail == head){
        Node next = new Node(info);
        tail.next = next;
        head = next;
        head.previous = tail;
    } else{
        Node next = new Node(info);
        Node current = head;
        head.next =next;
        head = next;
        head.previous = current;
    }
}
}
```